# how to limit the number of jobs running on the same node using SLURM?

Tags: slurm

I have a job array of 100 jobs. I want at most 2 jobs from the job array can be allocated to the same node. How can I do this using SLURM? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that jobs can share nodes, and that nodes have homogeneous configuration, and that you are alone on the cluster,

1. use the `sinfo -Nl` command to find the number of CPUs per nodes
2. submit jobs that request half that number with either of `#SBATCH --tasks-per-node=...` or `#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=...` based on what your jobs do

If you are administrating a cluster that is shared among other people, you can define `GRES` of a dummy type, and assign two of them to each node in `slurm.conf` and then request one per job with `--gres=dummy:1`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I'm not alone on the cluster and I'm not administrating the cluster either, is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Not easily without help from an administrator.

Comment: When should I use `--tasks-per-node` vs `--cpus-per-task`?

Comment: typically `--tasks-per-node` for distributed memory (MPI processes) and `--cpus-per-task` for shared-memory (threads, etc.)